# Format a string like you would a numeric value

Tags: c#, string

I have a string that I would like to format the same way I would a numeric value.
Ex:

```
int num = 2;
string option = num.ToString("000");
Console.WriteLine(option);
//output
//002
```

But the only way I can think to format it is to parse it as an int, then apply the ToString("000") method to it.

```
string option = "2";
option = int.Parse(option).ToString("000");
```

Is there a better, more direct way to do this?

Comment: What's wrong with converting it to an integer? That's how you want it to represent, so why not treat it as such?

Comment: You seem to have found a way that works. Do you have an issue with it? Is the issue that it's too many lines of codes? Why not turn it into an extension method?

Comment: How does this work? `string option = 2;`?  This shouldn't even compile.

Comment: It just seems like there would be a more direct way, rather than having to convert the same thing twice. This is being used in a fairly slow 3rd party application, so anything i can make run slightly quicker helps

Comment: Sorry, `X` returns hex, it should be `D` as shown in Donals answer.

Comment: @tinonw01 If your application is running slowly, converting integers is the least of your concerns.

Comment: @Jashaszun, it is not MY application, it is a program called Epicor. I'm just looking for efficiency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no built-in mechanism to "format" a string as if it were a number.  Some options:

- Use string functions (`Pad`, `Length`, `Substring`) to determine what characters should be added
- Parse to a numeric type and use `ToString` with numeric formatting strings
- Use a reqular expression to extract the digits and generate a new string

There's not one "right" answer.  Each has risks and benefits in terms of safety (what if the string does not represent a valid integer?), readability, performance, etc.

Comment: I agree but i think OP is not worry about string that if its a number. since is using `int.Parse`.btw i think regex would be nicer.

Answer (score 0):

Would this suit your requirement?

```
string x = "2";
string formattedX = x.PadLeft(3, '0');
Console.WriteLine(formattedX);  //prints 002
```